# Beautiful soup xml tags (<>) when converting to text with .text, becomes very unstructured text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e34780e3000008c00d964dd').text  
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
print(soup)
```

output:

```
 <textarea cols="100" name="olidata" readonly="" rows="40">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
&lt;EVENT spec="IDL:o2bcs/automator/common/tasklistEvents:1.0#tasklistupdateevent"&gt;
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<event spec="IDL:o2bcs/automator/common/tasklistEvents:1.0#tasklistupdateevent">
  <tasklistoli>
    <bpid>
      <oid>B32028040:M11</oid>
      <type>MIGOPT1</type>
    </bpid>
    <oli>
      <tolicontrol>
        <oliid>1</oliid>
        <externalid1></externalid1>
        <externalid2></externalid2>
        <highlevelstatus>1</highlevelstatus>
        <status>550</status>
        <catalogue>14</catalogue>
        <errorcode>500220</errorcode>
        <errorstring>Unable to select the given SI COMP for deletion.</errorstring>
        <subscriptionid></subscriptionid>
        <activityid></activityid>
        <activityaccesscode></activityaccesscode>
        <dateofnetworkexecution></dateofnetworkexecution>
      </tolicontrol>
      <toli_1>
        <discriminator>29</discriminator>
        <tmigopt>
```

this gives me well spaced structured XML (type =bs4.BeautifulSoup)

now if i append my code with

```
    print(soup.text)
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\r\n<EVENT spec="IDL:o2bcs/automator/common/tasklistEvents:1.0#tasklistupdateevent">\r\n  \r\n\r\n  \r\n    \r\n      B32028040:M11\r\n      MIGOPT1\r\n    \r\n    \r\n      \r\n        1\r\n        \r\n        \r\n        1\r\n        550\r\n        14\r\n        500220\r\n        Unable to select the given SI COMP for deletion.\r\n        \r\n        \r\n        \r\n        \r\n      \r\n      \r\n        29\r\n        \r\n          \r\n            \r\n              524742\r\n              40193375\r\n              \r\n              \r\n              40003859\r\n              MOB\r\n              o2UniteBasicService\r\n              O2P0058\r\n              2018-05-08 00:00:00\r\n              \r\n              \r\n              \r\n              N\r\n              \r\n              \r\n              \r\n              2014-07-09 00:00:00\r\n              0\r\n              \r\n              \r\n                O2O0014\r\n                \r\n                524742\r\n                SIM
```

this gives me very bad and unstructured data, (type = str)

i am planning to use regex on the text but need proper data, please help

Comment: The source is what you want (print(source)). What data do you want to extract?

Comment: source is string form of my requested link page,
i want the paragraph part (soup.p) in text form but when i do .text it give me bad data  instead of  " <> " i am getting something like " \r\n    \r\n "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand your exact needs. Let me give you an example to see if it will help you

```
from simplified_scrapy.request import req
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html = req.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e34780e3000008c00d964dd') 
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.event.text) # Output the text in the event tag
print ('-'*50)
# Traverse all nodes
def test(ele):
    if isinstance(ele,list):
        for e in ele:
            test(e)
        return
    children = ele.children
    if children:
        for e in children:
            test(e)
    else:
        print (ele.tag,ele.text)

test(doc.event.children)
```